# Как проверить, подключен ли пользователь к WebSocket-у

Tags: asp.net-core, angular, websocket

Всем привет. Мне необходимо отправить сообщение пользователю через WebSocket.
Проблема в том, что я должен быть уверен, что клиент принял сообщение.
Можно ли из коробки, посредством функциональности SignalR узнать подключен ли пользователь?

Comment: Шли отчет о доставке с клиента. Остальные методы не надежны

Answer (score 0):

могу предложить вот такое решение  - но это только разработка
код вставить не смог

[image: проверить при подключении к разговору == находиться ли Respondent В СЕТИ, или на странице Диалогов, или НЕ В СЕТИ]

Comment: // Id User - ID пользователя (пример: 14) 
 // Context.ConnectionId - имя (пример: 03e42e5b-4946-4a7f-9a1c-2e29f9f48ade)
 private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> UsersToChatHub = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
 // Id User - ID пользователя (пример: 14) 
 // roomName - имя группы (пример: user 12, user 26)
 private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> UsersRoom = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
 // Id User - ID пользователя (пример:14) 
 private string idUser;

Comment: Пока только не могу понять как точно определять что собеседник покинул комнату чата через закрытие браузера - вот это решение ищу

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)